# Custom pipe not found ionic 4 | pipe not found

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hey guys imma new ionic programmer, im currently developing an app which use youtube api(show videos from a single channel). I´ve followed a tutorial and im doing the same thing as him but mines get this error.

```
The pipe 'youtube' could not be found
```

even though i created and imported the youtube pipe as the tutorial showed.
These are my codes

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {YoutubePipe} from './youtube.pipe';



@NgModule({
declarations:
  [AppComponent, YoutubePipe],
entryComponents: [],
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpModule],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my youtube.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
name: 'youtube',
})
export class YoutubePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer) {

}

transform(value: string) {
console.log(this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value ));
return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value);
}
}
```

And this one is my home.page.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-title>
  Videos
</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of posts">
<ion-card-title>
{{item.snippet.title}}
</ion-card-title>
<ion-card-content>
  <!--img [src]="item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url"/>-->
  <iframe [src]="item.id.videoId | youtube" width="100%" height="315"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

This last one is my home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';



@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

search: String = 'ionic 4';
posts: any = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&channelId=UCHm8H-_IZMLl4-HYwrsvtNQ&maxResults=20&key=AIzaSyCQuzbBfetLjteTBAoSV3oCM3Mf_dstU6Q';
this.http.get(url).pipe(map(res => res.json())).subscribe(data => {
  this.posts = this.posts.concat(data.items);
  console.log(this.posts);
});

}

}
```

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of it. Also, if possible, try posting a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com, reproducing your issue.

Comment: im sorry, this is my first post thats why.
but i just changed it.

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-w9m4gr?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts
It works fine for me

Comment: @Xavier no problem, that's why I tell you that !

Comment: @nircraft which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",

Comment: Im using 4. I dont know but, im running my code on stackblitz and its working and on my local its not. Do you think its the version of my ionic? @nircraft

Comment: It could be, seems ~4.0 is still in beta.. you can stay on 3.9.2 to stay out of any issues

Comment: thank you, ill try now, then i will post the result

Comment: @nircraft thank you my friend it worked perfectly, the problem was the ionic 4.
I dont even know the reason but its working.
Thank you <3

Comment: @BelithoXavier, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following solution, to use a cutom pipe in a component in Ionic 4.
Remove the pipe from app.module.ts

Import the pipe in your page module. e.g. home.module.ts

```
import { CustomPipe } from '../../app/custom.pipe';
```

Add this to the declarations in home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  entryComponents: [NewssliderComponent],
  declarations: [HomePage, CustomPipe, NewssliderComponent]
})
```

The you can use the pipe in the newsslider.component.html file

```
{{e.publish | CustomPipe}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't import your pipe into app.module.ts. Instead create a file called `pipe.module.ts` with the following code in it:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { YoutubePipe } from './youtube.pipe';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        YoutubePipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        YoutubePipe
    ]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Then import this PipesModule into your `home.module.ts` where you are using the pipe. Also make sure to remove the `import { YoutubePipe } from './youtube.pipe'` from `app.module.ts` as it is not necessary to have that import in app.module.ts.

Comment: this should be accepted as the answer as it helps import the same pipe on multiple pages in ionic 4